# How to execute multiple bash commands from Python?

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, python-3.x, subprocess

I have a grep query:

```
grep  "8=ABC\.4\.[24].*\|10=[0-9]+" output.txt |grep "35=8"| cut -d "|" -f 12 >redirect.txt
```

How do I execute the same from inside a python script? I know for a simple grep it works as follows:

```
sed_process = subprocess.Popen(['sed', sed_query,fopen], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) 
grep_query = "8=ABC\.4\.[24].*\|10=[0-9]+"
grep_process = subprocess.Popen(['grep', grep_query], stdin=sed_process.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I'm confused as to how to combine 2 grep commands and a `cut` command and redirect it to an output file?

Comment: Why are you using all those other programs rather than writing it in Python ?  They don't do anything you can't do in Python, you might as well write a shell script.

Answer (score 2):

As addressed in the comments, this could all be implemented in python without calling anything. But if you want to make external calls, just keep chaining like you did in your example. The final stdout is an open file to finish off with the redirection. Notice I also close parent side stdout so that it doesn't keep an extra entry point to the pipe.

```
import subprocess as subp

p1 = subp.Popen(["grep", "8=ABC\.4\.[24].*\|10=[0-9]+", "output.txt"],
    stdout=subp.PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()
p2 = subp.Popen(["grep", "35=8"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subp.PIPE)
p2.stdout.close()
p3 = subp.Popen(["cut", "-d", "|", "-f", "12"], stdin=p2.stdout, 
    stdout=open('redirect.txt', 'wb'))
p3.wait()
p2.wait()
p1.wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

For `cut` it's exactly the same as for `grep`.  To redirect to a file at the end, simply `open()` a file and pass that as `stdout` when running the `cut` command.